# Add commands for PropertyGrid

Tags: winforms, propertygrid

I feel that it's something elementary but I can't find out how to add to class commands for PropertyGrid.

There is a sample class (the real classes are much more complex, but I need only the simplest example to implement the required functionality)

```
Public Class SampleClass
    Public Const DefValue = 1
    Public Property Value1 As Integer = DefValue
    Public Property Value2 As Integer = DefValue
    Public Sub Reset()
        Value1 = DefValue
        Value2 = DefValue
    End Sub
End Class
```

Used In the sample form:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.PropertyGrid1 = New System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'PropertyGrid1
        '
        Me.PropertyGrid1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(242, 98)
        Me.PropertyGrid1.Name = "PropertyGrid1"
        Me.PropertyGrid1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(294, 250)
        Me.PropertyGrid1.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(7.0!, 15.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.PropertyGrid1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents PropertyGrid1 As PropertyGrid
End Class
```

An instance is attached to PropertyGrid by the next piece of code:

```
Public Class Form1
   Private Sample As New SampleClass
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = Sample
   End Sub
End Class
```

The goal is to have a link that resets the contents of the instance at bottom of PropertyGrid like in the picture below, I presume that some attribute for a class is required but can't find what attribute.

[image]

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It's a bit more complex than a bunch of attributes. You must add a DesignerAttribute (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerattribute) to the class and implement a designer with custom verbs, like in this complete sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ms229066(v=vs.120)

Comment: It looks like you want to attach this class to a PropertyGrid at run-time, not at design-time. In this case, you need to provide a custom IServiceProvider (an object that implements `ISite`) that also implements [IMenuCommandService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.imenucommandservice), which provides a run-time `DesignerVerbCollection` (`Verbs` property), hence your class should implement `IComponent` (to set the custom ISite / IMenuCommandService). When you add a new `DesignerVerb`, you can set method (public or not) of your class as custom action

Comment: I don't remember what service you have to ask for to refresh the PropertyGrid when you have reset the values of some of the properties, since simply decorating the class with `[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]` won't do it at run-time